# Return value from other class delegate

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I created a class (UIView) which has a UIScrollview inside. Through the delegate "scrollViewDidEndDecelerating" I can have 3 results (1,2,3).
How do I send this result to the main ViewController?

**ViewController header**

```
#import "Picker.h"
```

**ViewController implementation**

```
picker = [[Picker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300)];
[self.view addSubview:picker];
```

**Picker implementation**

```
(...)

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 100) {

        int result = 1;

    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 100 && scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 200) {

        int result = 2;

    } else {

        int result = 3;

    }
}

(...)
```

I had to create a UIView class because it has other things in addition to Scrollview.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a `PickerDelegate` protocol with a method to return the required value to the main view controller.

```
@protocol PickerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)picker:(Picker *)picker didScrollToResult:(NSInteger)result;

@end
```

The Picker has a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<PickerDelegate> delegate;
```

Then you can set your view controller as the picker delegate using `picker.delegate = self;`

In the Picker UIView's scrollview delegate method, you can pass the message to the view controller by using:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 100) {
        int result = 1;
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 100 && scrollView.contentOffset.x <= 200) {
        int result = 2;
    } else {
        int result = 3;
    }
    [self.delegate picker:self didScrollToResult:result];
}
```

The view controller needs to implement the picker delegate method:

```
-(void)picker:(Picker *)picker didScrollToResult:(NSInteger)result {
    // View controller now has result variable to action upon.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a property within your `Picker` class:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) MyViewController* controller;
```

and initalize Picker's instances like this:

```
picker = [[Picker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300) andController:self];
```

then you could do:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    [self.controller myMethod]; 
    ...
```

This is known as dependency injection and it is ok if it makes sense create such strong coupling among the two classes. You could create a delegate protocol to give such interaction a fuller status.

Another option you have, which allows you to avoid the coupling, is using notifications through `NSNotificationCenter`.

In this case, one object (your controller) would register for observing a `PickerScrollViewChanged` notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) name:kPickerScrollViewChanged object:nil];
```

a `picker` would send such notification from its `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kPickerScrollViewChanged object:self];
```

Comment: thanks, but in this way the class can not be used in multiple classes.

Comment: why not? you decide what signature has your method, if you need to pass in a reference to the picker, you are welcome... indeed, this is what I do with the notification example...

Answer (score 1):

In your view controller class, you should add observer(register for notification) into viewDidLoad method.
Inside `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` you should post a notification.

So, in viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(scrollViewZoomed:)
 name:@"scrollViewDidZoom"
 object:nil];
```

Inside your scrollViewDidEndDecelerating,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:@"scrollViewDidZoom"
 object:self];
```

Do not forget to remove observer when its not required.